# javascript - execute function after for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function where onclick a button will get all the id of selected task from a gantt chart and run a for loop to save each of the selected task i edited in a form using AJAX request.

The problem now on AJAX request `success` I add a code to clear and load all the data again in the gantt chart but it doesn't goes as intended, load the data several times and start creating duplicate of the same data in my gantt, I tried to execute the `gantt.load` function outside of the loop and it still not working.

So how can I create a condition where I reload the gantt AFTER the loop is finish executed? Any help is much appreciated thanks.

Below is my code :

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="editForm()">Edit</button>
```

javascript

```
 function editForm() {
            var selected_task = gantt.getSelectedTasks();

            for (var i = 0; i < selected_task.length; i++) {
                var task = selected_task[i];
                var data = gantt.getTask(task);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'PUT',
                        url: '/api/dashboard/workorder_detail/' + data.workorder_id + '/',
                        data: postData,
                        success: function () {
                            $('#edit_form_modal').modal('hide');
                            gantt.clearAll();
                            gantt.load("/api/scheduler/{{ selected_project.id }}/?format=json", "json");

                        },
                        error: function (err) {
                            alert("Failed because of " + err);
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
```

Comment: `AJAX` calls are asynchronous, due to this you cannot expect synchronous code `for` to wait for an asynchronous code to finish because you do not have the result at the moment the code is executed and therefore you have to wait for the result, i suggest to implement this using `Promises` as it can allow you to wait for all the asynchronous code and execute function when there's a result

Answer (score 1):

Map selected tasks to a list of promises and use [jQuery when](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to load the gantt after all the promises have resolved.

```
function editForm() {
  var selected_task = gantt.getSelectedTasks();

  var saveSelectedTask = selected_task.map(function(task, i) {
    var data = gantt.getTask(task);
    return $.ajax({
      type: 'PUT',
      url: '/api/dashboard/workorder_detail/' + data.workorder_id + '/',
      data: postData,
    });
  });

  $.when(saveSelectedTask)
    .done(function() {
      $('#edit_form_modal').modal('hide');
      gantt.clearAll();
      gantt.load("/api/scheduler/{{ selected_project.id }}/?format=json", "json");
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
      alert("Failed because of " + err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @Oluwafemi Thanks for you reply, it helps, but it appear the refresh is still a bit too fast, when the page finish reload some of the data still havent updated yet, so a add a `setTimeout()` on the `gantt.load`, it works but not effiecient, do you have any rocommendation for this?

Answer (score 1):

in this case, you should use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), exactly is [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) (I suggest you go to these URLs to learn more about Promise before implement.
The idea is letting the request run parallel, then wait for all finish and do your callback.

I will rewrite your JS to:

```
function editForm() {
         var selected_task = gantt.getSelectedTasks();
          Promise.all(selected_task.map(function(task) {
            var data = gantt.getTask(task);
            return $.ajax({
                    type: 'PUT',
                    url: '/api/dashboard/workorder_detail/' + data.workorder_id + '/',
                    data: postData,
                })
        }).then(function(results) {
           $('#edit_form_modal').modal('hide');
           gantt.clearAll();
           gantt.load("/api/scheduler/{{ selected_project.id }}/?format=json", "json");

        })
    }
```

update: if you'd prefer to use jQuery function, then you can use $.when()

```
 function editForm() {
         var selected_task = gantt.getSelectedTasks();
          $.when(selected_task.map(function(task) {
            var data = gantt.getTask(task);
            return $.ajax({
                    type: 'PUT',
                    url: '/api/dashboard/workorder_detail/' + data.workorder_id + '/',
                    data: postData,
                })
        }).then(function(results) {
           $('#edit_form_modal').modal('hide');
           gantt.clearAll();
           gantt.load("/api/scheduler/{{ selected_project.id }}/?format=json", "json");

        })
    }
```

but as I said above, solve the problem doesn't make you better, should dig deep into it and learn how functions works.

Comment: Hi @Kai Thanks for you reply, it helps and I appreciate the advice, i will study more on this, just 1 more thing, it appear the refresh is still a bit too fast, when the page finish reload some of the data still havent updated yet, so a add a `setTimeout()` on the `gantt.load`, it works but not effiecient, do you have any rocommendation for this?

Comment: @M.Izzat I think you should check the update code is working correct or not. Maybe the data was cached.